# Proper way to hide detailView when nothing is selected in master on ios

Tags: ios, master-detail

I've searched here for a solution to this and have not found any posts on this topic.

I would like my detail view to simply display a "No object selected" message when the master table view has no selection.  This is somewhat complicated by the fact that the selection can be lost on several different occasions, such as when the tableView enters edit mode, when a single cell enters edit mode (swipe for delete), or when the program operates on the table (as in reordering it).

Any ideas on how this could be accomplished?  This seems like it would be a fairly standard behavior, so I have a feeling I'm missing something simple.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `tableView:willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` doesn't catch every case, you'll just need to catch the individual cases and call some identical method in each.

By the way, I trust you understand that the detail view displaying "No object selected" will itself be a full fledged detail view.

Comment: I am using a label with an opaque background to cover the detail view, which I plan to simply show and hide in order to cover the detailView.  Is this a bad way to accomplish this?

willDeselectRowAtIndexPath is almost never the method I need, since the only way the user can deselect is by selecting another cell.  I can catch it for swipe to delete by showing the label in `tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:` How can I catch when they tap Edit? Putting the code in `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` does the trick, but it seems like a poor workaround as it gets called multiple times.

Comment: Oh - well, I suppose it depends on how you're managing the detail view when the user selects a master row in the first place.

Comment: Ok, I think I've got it, with your hint, matt. With a combination of `tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath`, `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, and overriding the `setEditing:animated:` (that was the piece I was missing), I was able to achieve the functionality I wanted, by simply showing or hiding the covering label appropriately. And as a reminder to anyone else trying to achieve this, if you override setEdinting:animated, be sure to include a call to super at the end: `[super setEditing:editing animated:animated];`. Thanks for your help matt!